# Crystal Reports Dynamic Cascading Parameters

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that is using dynamic parameters with ~8 levels of selectable criteria:

```
Company,    
Country,
Zone,
Division,
State,
Region,
Area,
City,
Center
```

I want to have a list of each item cascading down, but also have ALL as an option for each.  I also want to be able to have some of the top levels be ALL and then those in the middle be selectable then go to ALL again.  For instance I don't want to select a company, country, zone, or division but select a State and a Region and then have the Area, City, and Center go back to all.

My table has about 2000 records and my initial solution was to structure it where I was doing the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Company,
    Country,
    Zone,
    Division,
    State,
    Region,
    Area,
    City,
    Center
FROM myTable 

UNION ALL
SELECT
    Company = 'All',
    Country = 'All',
    Zone = 'All',
    Division = 'All',
    State = 'All',
    Region = 'All',
    Area = 'All',
    City = 'All',
    Center = 'All'

UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    Company = 'All',
    Country,
    Zone = 'All',
    Division = 'All',
    State = 'All',
    Region = 'All',
    Area = 'All',
    City = 'All',
    Center = 'All'
FROM myTable
```

Using about every combination I could think of.  This not only seems convuluted but causes a massive amount of data to be returned and seems like something can be missed.

My primary concern is to have All be selectable for any of the options in addition to what hasn't been filtered by a selection from a higher level.

Is there any way to do this without having 40-50 UNION ALL statements to account for everything I need?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: crystal is really poor for this sort of thing. is it your only option? ssrs handles this a lot better! how about having a custom .net application on the front-end, is that an option?

Comment: Crystal is the only option unfortunately.  The report is ran from the CE repository so the custom application isn't an option either.

Comment: I've had a lot of difficulty figuring out how to use 'ALL' or making Crystal select based on OR with prompt use. Plus 'ALL' just looks messy when its not the first value in a sorted field.